# Pandas: Reading excel files when the first row is NOT the column name Excel Files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using pandas to read an excel file. It doesn't have column name but it continues to read the first row as the column name.

Following is the excel file that is being read.

```
data1   0.994676
data2   0.994588
data3   0.99488
data4   0.994483
data5   0.994312
data6   0.993823
data7   0.993575
data8   0.994231
data9   0.993838
data10  0.994007
data11  0.994328
data12  0.993503
data13  0.99342
data14  0.992729
data15  0.993013
data16  0.993049
data17  0.993133
data18  0.99262
```

I'm reading the 2nd column using the following code.
import pandas as pd

```
df=pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/080718_output.xlsx', header=None, index_col=False).parse('Data_sheet')
y=df.iloc[0:17,1]
```

The following is the y.

```
In[38]:y
Out[38]: 
0     0.994588
1     0.994880
2     0.994483
3     0.994312
4     0.993823
5     0.993575
6     0.994231
7     0.993838
8     0.994007
9     0.994328
10    0.993503
11    0.993420
12    0.992729
13    0.993013
14    0.993049
15    0.993133
16    0.992620
Name: 0.994676, dtype: float64
```

It skips the first data because the first row is being used as a column name..
Any idea on how I can improve this?

Edit: 'header=False' to 'header=None'. Both cases give the same outcome.

Comment: Do you need `header=None` ?

Comment: Hi, I have tried both but it doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: you are right, it not working for me too.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) with `header=None` for default columns with `rangeIndex`:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', 
                   sheet_name ='Data_sheet', 
                   header=None, 
                   index_col=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a column header variable and call that in your excel read in statement as well as stating header=None

```
names=['Column1','Column2']
df=pd.read_excel(r"/Users/JohnDoe/Desktop/080718_output.xlsx",header=None,names=names)
```